# Converting list of strings to numbers

Tags: powershell

I have a directory whose subdirectories are all numbers:

```
./2856
./2357
./10198
```

and so on.

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that would return the largest subdirectory name smaller than X.

So in this example, for the input 3000 it should return 2856.

However what I've written so far looks **very** cumbersome to me, and I'm wondering how it can be shortened:

```
Get-ChildItem "$path" ` 
| ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } `
| Select-Object @{Name="AsInt"; Expression={[int]$_.Name}} `
| Select-Object -expand AsInt `
| ?{$_ -lt [int]$lessThanNumber} `
| measure-object -max `
| Select-Object -expand Maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
Get-ChildItem "$path" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and [int]$_.name -le 3000} `
 | Sort-Object -Property @{exp={[int]$_.name}} `
 | Select-Object -Last 1
```

You can write it :

```
Get-ChildItem "$path" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and [int]$_.name -le 3000} `
 | Sort -Property @{exp={[int]$_.name}} `
 | Select -Last 1
```

If you want to avoid errors due to these directory names which are not integers :

```
Get-ChildItem "$path" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.name -as [int]) -le 3000} `
  | Sort -Property @{exp={$_.name -as [int]}} `
  | Select -Last 1
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `$lessThanNumber` instead of 3000?

Comment: Yes it was the way I was understandig your question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with PowerShell v3:

```
$max = 3000
$cur = 0

ls -d | %{
    # Potential for issues if the directory name cannot be cast to [int]
    $name = ([int]$_.Name)
    if (($name -gt $cur) -and ($name -le $max)) {
        $cur = $name
    }
}
```

($cur = 2856 at the end)

Answer (score 1):

If you have V3:

```
@(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Name |
ForEach-Object {$_ -as [int]}) -lt $LessThanNumber |
sort | select -last 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With PowerShell v3:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -dir | Select *,@{n='Number';e={[int]$_.Name}} | 
    Where Number -lt $lessThanNumber | Sort Number | Select -Last 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another (v3) example. Only directory names that contain numbers are passed on and the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet is used to evaluate the name into a number (no explicit cast is needed)

```
$x = 3000

Get-ChildItem -Directory | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -notmatch '\D' -and (Invoke-Expression $_.Name) -lt $x
} | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Last 1
```